# Creating DLL in Cobol

Tags: dll, cobol

I need to create a DLL in cobol with external functions to perform Open and Read on Dat Files. My objective is to use the return with a string so anyother IDE could use this DLL to perform Sql Operations.

How can i transform the "Perform" in cobol into a Function External in a DLL with a return string?

Comment: Well of course you can't. Why don't you tell us, in words, what you want to achieve, without imagining how something may be done. Although you could take the code of an open-source COBOL compiler and change it to do what you state, but I don't think you'd really want to do that.

Comment: This time, after your attempt on the IBM COBOL Cafe, are you going to tell us even which compiler and OS you are using?

Comment: I need to read a DAT file in Delphi or Visual Studio. During my search, i've found that was possible to create a DLL in cobol with the basic Open, Read Write... commands on Dat Files.

I'm Using Visual Cobol Acubench 8.1 on Windows 7 and i have access to the files .FD .SL .XFD .DLT.


Thanks

Comment: You need to add that information into your question, and do some (quite a lot) clarification of exactly what you are wanting to do, which probably doesn't include changing anything to do with PERFORM, but likely instead using COBOL's CALL verb.

Comment: Well, thats exactly what i'm trying to do. But the lack of knowledge and i couldnt find in the documentation and web, how to write a code in COBOL  to be a external function of a DLL to return a string.

So... in theory it should be a Perform that Open a File (DAT), than read and move to a  Variable string.

Could u Help me with an exemple of code in visual cobol (Acubench) that is a function and not a perform 

Thanks

Comment: Have you not found things like this: http://supportline.microfocus.com/examplesandutilities/extend/TechnicalTips/tip13.asp and this: https://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/extend_and_acucobol/f/20/t/8733.aspx, amongst others.

Comment: I'm Not trying to use a DLL in COBOL, i want to transform de .ACU or .CBL in a DLL. The cobol becomes the DLL itself.

Comment: Well, I didn't see that coming. Why do you think you'd need to do anything to PERFORM? http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite%2FBKITITDOTNS007.html

Comment: Thats, how i'm compiling into a DLL, the problem is that i dont know how to create a external function with a return in this DLL using COBOL Code, so anyother IDE like Visual Studio or Delphi could use this DLL to read Dat Files.

Comment: Ah. Have a look at your documentation, you should see within the description of the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` header options for both `USING` and `RETURNING`. You define the returning-item in the LINKAGE SECTION. The USING would have the parameters to the "function" and the RETURNING is the return value. Is that, finally, what you are after?

Comment: Yep, it was very helpful

Comment: OK, good. If you can clarify your question, and post your own answer to it, it can help future searchers.